# Drag and drop subrip-file (.srt) from file-roller (archive manager) to VLC?

Tags: lubuntu, vlc, subtitle

When I drag a subtitle file straight from an open zip like so:
[image]

It doesn't load the subtitle file. Dragging the subtitles works only if I extract the subtitle file first and then drag it. 
Is there a way to make it work straight from a zip file as it does in Windows?

I use Lubuntu 14.04 LTS.